Приложение MAUI под Windows: ошибка COMException: Не обнаружено установленных компонентов
Пишу простое GUI приложение под MAUI. Отлаживаю его под Windows. GUI приложения представляет собой таблицу на основе Maui.Controls.Grid. В ячейках таблицы вставлены кнопки для управления этими ячейками. Одна из функций добавляющая элементы в таблицу:
private void OnAddHomeworkClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    int column = ScheduleGrid.GetColumn(button);
    int row = ScheduleGrid.GetRow(button);

    if (column >= 4) return;

    Entry homeworkEntry = new Entry();
    ScheduleGrid.Children.Add(homeworkEntry);
    ScheduleGrid.SetRow(homeworkEntry, row);
    ScheduleGrid.SetColumn(homeworkEntry, column);

    var deleteButton = CreateDeleteButtonForHomework(homeworkEntry);
    ScheduleGrid.Children.Add(deleteButton);
    ScheduleGrid.SetRow(deleteButton, row);
    ScheduleGrid.SetColumn(deleteButton, column);

    ScheduleGrid.Children.Remove(button);
    ScheduleGrid.Children.Add(button);
    ScheduleGrid.SetRow(button, row);
    ScheduleGrid.SetColumn(button, column + 1);
}

Определение ScheduleGrid:
private global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Grid ScheduleGrid;

Соответствующий XAML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="автономный_дневник_2.MainPage">

    <StackLayout Padding="10">
        <Label Text="Реестр предметов"
               FontSize="Large"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
           Margin="0,20,0,20" />

        <Grid x:Name="ScheduleGrid"
              RowSpacing="1"
              ColumnSpacing="1"
              Margin="0,10,0,10"
              RowDefinitions="*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*"
              ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*,*,*">
            <Button Text="+" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Clicked="OnAddSubjectClicked"/>
        </Grid>
        <Button Text="Go to Second Page"
                VerticalOptions="End"
                HorizontalOptions="End"
                Clicked="OnNavigateButtonClicked" />
        </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>

Эта функция в ячейку где находится нажатая кнопка добавляет homeworkEntry и deleteButton, а нажатую кнопку оттуда убирает и перемещает её в следующую свободную ячейку.
И почему-то при попытке выполнить строку ScheduleGrid.Children.Add(button); вылетает исключение System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException с сообщением об ошибке: Не обнаружено установленных компонентов. Код ошибки: 800F1000, собственно означает то же самое. Что за компоненты не установлены - загадка.
Стек вызовов:
   at WinRT.DelegateExtensions.DynamicInvokeAbi(Delegate del, Object[] invoke_params)
   at ABI.System.Collections.Generic.IListMethods`2.InsertAtDynamic(IObjectReference obj, UInt32 index, T value)
   at ABI.System.Collections.Generic.IVectorMethods`1.InsertAt(IObjectReference obj, UInt32 index, T value)
   at ABI.System.Collections.Generic.IListMethods`1.InsertAtHelper(IObjectReference obj, UInt32 index, T item)
   at ABI.System.Collections.Generic.IListMethods`1.Insert(IObjectReference obj, Int32 index, T item)
   at Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.UIElementCollection.Insert(Int32 index, UIElement item)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.LayoutHandler.Add(IView child)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.LayoutHandler.MapAdd(ILayoutHandler handler, ILayout layout, Object arg)
   at Microsoft.Maui.CommandMapper`2.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<Add>b__0(IElementHandler h, IElement v, Object o)
   at Microsoft.Maui.CommandMapper.InvokeCore(String key, IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView, Object args)
   at Microsoft.Maui.CommandMapper.Invoke(IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView, String property, Object args)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.Invoke(String command, Object args)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Layout.NotifyHandler(String action, Int32 index, IView view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Layout.OnAdd(Int32 index, IView view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Grid.OnAdd(Int32 index, IView view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Layout.Add(IView child)

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно определить каких неустановленных компонентов не хватает?

Версия винды старая?

@aepot Windows 10 Pro 19045.5131. Это старая?

Да не, вроде норм.

На ваш вопрос на EnSO, еще 25 числа обратил внимание сотрудник Microsoft (судя по нику), ответственный за MAUI (судя по его ответам) который явно знает куда больше, чем рандомные люди РУ SO... Вы его игнорируете, но начинаете конкурс и пытаетесь привлечь больше внимаения. Не кажется это... странным? У вас не типичная проблема, может даже баг, который надо разбирать, а вы игнорируете сотрудника MS....

@EvgeniyZ ну значит нужны более чёткое описание алгоритмов/протоколов взаимодействия пользователей с этим сайтом. Я не являюсь завсегдатаем этого сайта и не знаю всех правил от и до в деталях. Значит в диалоге открытия конкурса нужно добавить дополнительный шаг в котором пользователь должен подтвердить что конкурс соответствует тому что вы пишете. Там такого требования не было.

Вы мне чего претензии предъявляете? Я вам просто сказал то, что вы игнорируете человека, но запрашиваете везде "больше внимания". Это странно! Ну а человек, которого вы проигнорировали, судя по всему, сотрудник той компании, технологию которой вы используете, а это в двойне страннее делает всю ситуацию. И вы вместо того, чтобы пойти и ответить тому сотруднику, заагрились тут на меня, простого (как и вы) пользователя, что еще страннее. Перестаньте страдать ерундой и идите напишите тому человеку хоть что-то, чтобы он знал, что вопрос все еще актуален, ибо я не думаю, что он сидит и ждет.

Ответ на его вопрос я добавил в описание проблемы ещё кажется позавчера. И здесь эта информация тоже продублирована.
